# Spring Batch multiple readers for different DB's

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, arangodb

I have an existing spring batch project which reads data from MySQL or ArangoDB(NoSql database) based on feature toggle decision during startup and does some process and again writes back to MySQL/ArangoDB.

Now the reader configuration for MySQL is something like below,

```
@Bean
@Primary
@StepScope
public HibernatePagingItemReader reader(
        @Value("#{jobParameters[oldMetadataDefinitionId]}") Long oldMetadataDefinitionId) {

    Map<String, Object> queryParameters = new HashMap<>();
    queryParameters.put(Constants.OLD_METADATA_DEFINITION_ID, oldMetadataDefinitionId);


    HibernatePagingItemReader<Long> reader = new HibernatePagingItemReader<>();

    reader.setUseStatelessSession(false);
    reader.setPageSize(250);
    reader.setParameterValues(queryParameters);

    reader.setSessionFactory(((HibernateEntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory.getObject()).getSessionFactory());
    return reader;
}
```

and i have another arango reader like below,

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ListItemReader arangoReader(
        @Value("#{jobParameters[oldMetadataDefinitionId]}") Long oldMetadataDefinitionId) {

    List<InstanceDTO> instanceList = new ArrayList<InstanceDTO>();

    PersistenceService arangoPersistence = arangoConfiguration
            .getPersistenceService());

    List<Long> instanceIds = arangoPersistence.getDefinitionInstanceIds(oldMetadataDefinitionId);

    instanceIds.forEach((instanceId) ->
    {
        InstanceDTO instanceDto = new InstanceDTO();
        instanceDto.setDefinitionID(oldMetadataDefinitionId);
        instanceDto.setInstanceID(instanceId);
        instanceList.add(instanceDto);

    });

    return new ListItemReader(instanceList);

}
```

and my step configuration is below,

```
@Bean
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Step InstanceMergeStep(ListItemReader arangoReader, ItemWriter<MetadataInstanceDTO> arangoWriter,
        ItemReader<Long> mysqlReader, ItemWriter<Long> mysqlWriter) {

    Step step = null;
    if (arangoUsage) {
        step = steps.get("arangoInstanceMergeStep")


                .<Long, Long>chunk(1)

                .reader(arangoReader)

                .writer(arangoWriter)


                .faultTolerant()


                .skip(Exception.class)


                .skipLimit(10)

                .taskExecutor(stepTaskExecutor())

                .build();


        ((TaskletStep) step).registerChunkListener(chunkListener);
    }
    else {
        step = steps.get("mysqlInstanceMergeStep")


                .<Long, Long>chunk(1)

                .reader(mysqlReader)

                .writer(mysqlWriter)

                .faultTolerant()

                .skip(Exception.class)


                .skipLimit(failedSkipLimit)

                .taskExecutor(stepTaskExecutor())

                .build();


        ((TaskletStep) step).registerChunkListener(chunkListener);

    }

    return step;
}
```

The MySQL reader has pagination support through HibernatePagingItemReader so that it will handle millions of items without any memory issue.

I want to implement the same pagination support for arango reader to fetch only 250 documents per iteration how can modify the arango reader code to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all documentation of [ListItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ListItemReader.html) says that - **Useful for testing** so don't use it for production. Return an `ItemReader` instead from all your reader beans instead of actual concrete types.

Having said that, Spring Batch API or Spring Data doesn't seem to supporting Arango DB . Closest that I could find is [this](https://github.com/anderick/spring-data-arangodb)

( I have not worked with Arango DB before ) .

So in my opinion, you have to write your own custom arango reader that implements paging by possibly implementing abstract class - [org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractPagingItemReader.html)

If its not doable by extending above class, you might have to implement everything from scratch. All of pagination readers in Spring Batch API extend this abstract class including `HibernatePagingItemReader`.

Also, remember that arango record set should have some kind of ordering to implement pagination so we can distinguish between page - 0 & page -1  etc ( similar to `ORDER BY` clause ,  `BETWEEN` Operator & less than , greater than operators etc in SQL. Also `FETCH FIRST XXX ROWS` OR `LIMIT` clause kind of thing would be needed too ) .

Implementing by your own is not a very tough task as you have to calculate total possible items , order them and then divide into pages and fetch only one page at a time.

Look at API for implementations like - `HibernatePagingItemReader` etc to get ideas.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks @sabir for above clarification!! , will it be possible to call the reader multiple times of arangoMergeStep with dynamic startIndex and endIndex to fetch only limited records for AQL queries using spring boot.

Comment: Its the `read()` method of reader that will be called repeatedly by framework. That `read()` method should keep returning one by one items till a page is finished and then fetch next page. you return `null` for last item of last page. Look at one of existing classes like - `JdbcPagingItemReader` or `HibernatePagingItemReader` etc. It will be your custom reader's job to maintain these items & counts since contract is to return a single item each time a read is called.